# Mandrill: SPF Permanent Error: Invalid domain found (use FQDN)

Tags: mandrill, spf

I'm trying to set up Mandrill with one of our client's domains but receiving the error when trying to set up the SPF record:

```
An unexpected error occurred while checking your domain: SPF Permanent Error: Invalid domain found (use FQDN): 123.123.123
```

The domain has a current SPF record as follows:

```
v=spf1 mx ptr ptr:123.123.123 ~all
```

As per Mandrill's instructions I should add to the existing record as follows:

```
v=spf1 mx ptr ptr:223.197.169.174 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ~all
```

Which results in the above error. I have also tried creating a new record instead, which Mandrill also didn't like. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 6):

The PTR mechanism should specify a domain-name and not an ip-address. If no domain is specified the default domain will be used.

But it is strongly discouraged using the PTR mechanism, since it can put a heavy load on the resolving server (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.5)

So I would think that a record looking like this would do it:

```
v=spf1 mx include:spf.mandrillapp.com ~all
```

Or

```
v=spf1 mx ptr include:spf.mandrillapp.com ~all
```

if you still want the `ptr` mechanism.

Comment: is 100% right, also switch the the `~all` to `-all`, if you're using SPF for what it's meant to be used for, might as well enforce it. If you want to test your SPF record you can do it a [Kitterman's Site](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) or sending an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com`

Comment: v=spf1 mx include:spf.mandrillapp.com ~all this worked for me